# VBA ScreenUpdate and efficiency

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I've created a 'driver' spreadsheet that controls (opens and runs etc) macros on other workbooks. I'm pressed for efficiency since the files I am working with are really large and cannot be altered further. I've read that application screen updating set to false helps. I've set the driver spreadsheet screen updating to false up top (and then back to true once the whole process is complete). However, when I run driver macro, the screen does update periodically (looks like it updates screen when opening another sub / macro / worksheet). The other subs / macros / workbooks that the driver opens also have screen updating set to false when starting and back to true at the end.

Can I set screen updating to false (and not revert to true when complete) for all other workbooks except for the driver? I've been reading that I must always set back to true... So it worries me.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether turning off screen updating really is saving you any time? Sometimes it does, like when charts get repeatedly updated by the VBA code. But other times it makes so little difference that it isn't worth worrying about at all.

Comment: I'd look at running a VBS or at least a VBA routine that does all the work in a new hidden instance of Excel

Answer (score 2):

Just to share, the method I use is like this:

```
Sub passiveRoutine()

Dim ScrnMode as Boolean

With Application
  ScrnMode = .Screenupdating
  If ScrnMode then .Screenupdating = False
End with

Do stuff


If ScrnMode then Application.Screenupdating = True
End Sub

Sub activeRoutine()

Dim ScrnMode as Boolean

With Application
  ScrnMode = .Screenupdating
  If Not ScrnMode then .Screenupdating = True
End with

Do stuff


If Not ScrnMode then Application.Screenupdating = False
End Sub
```

The idea is to avoid any unnecessary switching because sometimes it uses more time to switch modes than is saved by switching it off and also, it tends to reduce flickering of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to incorporate the requirement into your overall design.

Say you create a global boolean called **DriverInControl** that sub Driver could set/clear.  Each of the lower level subs would be modified to examine this flag.  If Driver sets the flag, Driver is announcing it is in control of screenupdating and the lower level sub would refrain from trying to control screenupdating.

If you are not running Driver, the global would be False by default and the lower level subs would assume control of screenupdating.